# Layman Question on Probability Amplitudes and Probabilities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, probability

**Important Note:** For "layman" read "next to zero understanding of QM mathematics"

I am reading Quantum Mechanics: The Theoretical Minimum. In Chapter 2 on Quantum States, the following is presented:

$$|A\rangle = a_u |u\rangle + a_d |d\rangle$$

and

$$a_u = \langle u|A\rangle$$
$$a_d = \langle d|A\rangle$$

where $|A\rangle$ is a generic state that can represent the state of a spin, and $a_u$, $a_d$ are components of $|A\rangle$ along the basis vectors $|u\rangle$ and $|d\rangle$.

The book then states that the probability that the spin will be up if measured along the z axis is $a_u^* a_u$, i.e., the square of the magnitude of the probability amplitude.

But then it presents:

$$P_u = \langle A|u\rangle \langle u|A\rangle$$

where $P_u$ is the probability of the spin being measured as up.

**My Question:**

Why isn't

$$P_u = \langle u|A\rangle \langle u|A\rangle$$

given what was stated earlier?

Comment: To format equations, use LaTex as in an usual .tex file. The complex conjugation of $\langle u, A\rangle$ is $\langle A,u\rangle=(\langle u, A\rangle)^*$.

Comment: @yuggib: Apologies, I'm not sure I understand your contribution. Is there a Latex app for android and if so, how would I add the .tex file (which I assume is generated from the Android app, if it exists) to my question?

Comment: No, he meant to say that you can type math as you would in a tex-file on this site, using `$ [typeset your math here] $`

Comment: They've used MathJax, which is enabled on this site. [This Tutorial explains some of what they mean](//physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Thanks all. And thank you to whomever fixed the equations in my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient $a_u = \langle u|A\rangle$ is allowed to be a complex number. The square of a complex number is also complex in general, but we do not want our probability to be complex. We therefore multiply $a_u$ with its complex conjugate $a_u^* = \langle A|u\rangle$, which always gives a real number.

Suppose that $a_u = x + yi$. The complex conjugate is given by $a_u^* = x - yi$. We can calculate that
$$a_ua_u=(x+yi)^2 = x^2 - y^2 +2xyi.$$ This number has an imaginary part; it is not a real number. On the other hand,
$$a_ua_u^*=(x + yi)(x - yi) = x^2 + y^2,$$
which is indeed a real number.

If you interpret the complex number $a_u$ to be vector/arrow in the [complex plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane), then $a_ua_u^*$ is the square of the length of the vector. So, besides being garanteed real, the product $a_ua_u^*$ also makes sense from a geometric point of view.

Comment: Thank you. The book does not mention that the probability is equal to the probability amplitude multiplied by its complex conjugate, it just says that it is equal to the probability amplitude squared. It also writes $a_u*a_u$…which looks like $a_u x a_u$           Odd that MathJax isn't allowed in comments…

Comment: The magnitude or "size" of the  probability amplitude $a_u$ -- or any other complex number -- is defined to be $|a_u| = \sqrt{a_ua_u^*}$. Squaring this magnitude gives us the desired result $|a_u|^2 = a_ua_u^*$. If the probability amplitude happens to be real, then $a_ua_u^*=a_u^2$, because the complex conjugate of real number is the number itself

Comment: I don't understand the comment…are you explaining more about your answer?

Comment: I am sorry if I am confusing you. I don't have your book at hand and am trying to give you some pointers as to why the book tells you that simply squaring the amplitudes is ok. The most likely reason is that the examples that you are looking at are using real coefficients $a_u$, rather than complex ones. If that is the case, you can simply square the coefficients to calculate the probability. When the coefficient is complex, you must multiply with the complex conjugate to get the correct probability.

Comment: No worries. To clear some things up…1) $a_u$ is a complex number in the book. 2) the book says that the probability amplitude must be squared in order to get the probability BUT it does NOT say that if the probability amplitude is a complex number, multiply it against its complex conjugate to get the probability

Comment: I advise you to look at how the book the defines the quantities. If the probibility amplitude is defined to be the "magnitude" of $a_u$, then the probability amplitude is given by $|a_u| = \sqrt{a_ua_u^*}$, rather than $a_u$. Then you can square $|a_u|$ and get the correct result $a_ua_u^*$. Or perhaps the book is a little sloppy with the term squaring. I can't tell you, but as you can see, it matters how things are defined. In any case, and there is no two ways about it, multiplying a complex number with itself gives a complex number, so that will not give you a sane probability.

Comment: @MonaLisaOverdrive I wouldn't be surprised if the book is just inconsistent. It is really hard for people who know as much as Susskind to start from the basics -- you have to both know where to simplify things, and remember what simplifications you made so you can remedy them later. I guess he forgot the second step.

Comment: @knzhou (and vosov), this is my bad…while summarizing the content for my question I left out this key part "…to compute a probability, their magnitudes must be squared" where "their" equals "probability amplitude"